# after i've upgraded to iOS version 7.1 my iOS app crashing on iPad 2 only, works fine on all other devices

Tags: delegates, ios7.1, ipad-2, nsexception

I've an iOS app for iPad & iPhone.
My app worked fine on all devices until now .
Now (after i've upgraded to iOS version 7.1) it crashes on ipad2 only.
On all other devices it has no problem.

At the startup of the app (and before calling viewDidLoad ).
I have this error:

```
(appDelegate Log)close didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 

2014-04-02 20:37:14.677 xxx[6436:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x2e438fd3 0x38f1bccf 0x2e372f9d 0x30d7bd89 0x30f229ff 0x30ce1589 0x30c5930d 0x30c59289 0x30c5fed9 0x30c5d847 0x30cc735d 0x30cc3fcd 0x30cbe58b 0x30c5a709 0x30c59871 0x30cbdcc9 0x33267aed 0x332676d7 0x2e403ab7 0x2e403a53 0x2e402227 0x2e36cf4f 0x2e36cd33 0x30cbcef1 0x30cb816d 0x441a9 0x44130)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I cannot understand why.
Thanks in advance.

-------- EDITED --------

I've solved by removing a unused button from the main View:

```
/* @synthesize myButton;*/

- (void)viewDidUnload {
   /* [self setMyButton:nil]; */
}
```

Comment: did you updated your xcode and ipad version to iOS 7.1?

Comment: When i've publushed my app, unfortunately ios 7.1 still had not existed

Comment: then edit and republish your app with iOS 7.1

Comment: Thank you. I solved and I edited my question. I hope it can be useful to someone